# Disable DropDownList inside Update Panel using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have the following Update Panel:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlTemplates" />
</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>
    <div class="left" id="dc_left" runat="server">
         <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlList" runat="server" CssClass="divToChange">
         </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And i want to disable from JQuery the dropdown using:

```
$divToChange.prop('disabled', true);
$(".divToChange").addClass('disabledControl');
```

The `disabledControl` class is added but the Drop Down is not disabled and i cant figure out why.
Can someone help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you double-checked `$divToChange` is the right object?

Comment: try with `attr` instead of `prop`

Comment: Jack, i tried using: var ddlList = $("#<%: ddlList.ClientID %>"); and ddlList.prop('disabled', true); but no luck. The object is correct, i print it in console.

Answer (score 0):

Join that with single statement

```
 $(".divToChange").addClass('disabledControl').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Tried this, the same results.

Comment: Then what the css content of `disabledControl` class? And what version of jQuery you used?

Comment: JQuery: 1.7.2. disableControl have 2 lines: background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border-color: #e5e5e5;

Comment: weird, your version already supported `.prop()` function. Ever try using `.attr()` like @liviupopovici said.

Answer (score 0):

You should try that with `ID` instead of `class`.

Here is the code

```
$('#ddlList').attr('disabled', true);
```

Also use `attr` instead of `prop`